# How to use ServiceStack OrmLite Sql.Count

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to use the Sql.Count, the compiler raised a type issue:  it returns the result with type T, but I want an int or long type.

```
var UsedTimesCount = conn.Scalar<AgencyFee,int>(
    f => Sql.Count(f.Id), 
    f => f.AgencyFeeTemplateId == feeTemplate.Id
);
```

Am I missing something?

The interface is:

```
public static T Count<T> (T value);
```

I expect:

```
public static long Count<T> (T value);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are [different API examples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/ApiSqliteTests.cs) of using Count in OrmLite:

```
db.Scalar<Person, int>(x => Sql.Count(x.Age), x => x.Id > 0);

db.Count<Person>(x => x.Age < 50);

db.Count(db.From<Person>().Where(x => x.Age < 50));

var q = db.From<Person>()
          .Where(q => q.Age > 40)
          .Select(Sql.Count("*"))
db.Scalar<int>(q);
```

Comment: Thank you mythz!
The `db.Count<Person>(x => x.Age < 50);` is better.
My connection is abstracted and without db.Count,  may add it later.

Answer (score 1):

I used `Sql.Sum(1)` to replace the `Sql.Count(f.Id)`:

```
var UsedTimesCount = conn.Scalar<AgencyFee,int>(
    f => Sql.Sum(1), 
    f => f.AgencyFeeTemplateId == feeTemplate.Id
);
```